# MFC Making a class extend both CView and CDockablePane

Tags: c++, mfc

So I want to take the current program I am working on and make all of the internal windows dockable. The only problem is that they extend a class called CFBView which extends CView. If I extend CDockablePane aswell, it will cause the Diamond of Death problem where it cannot compile properly.

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed the `CFBView` window inside a `CDockablePane` window. `CDockablePane` is the parent of `CFBView`.

There's no inheritance, `CFBView` is a member of `CDockablePane`.